# SSH with private/public keypair not working under proxy

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, encryption

I own a webserver. A friend of mine has an account on said webserver, to which he connects using his SSH private key, with his public key residing on my server.

The school that my friend attends has a self-signed certificate. All traffic on the network ends up at the proxy, which is then, if encrypted, decrypted and re-encrypted using the real key from the destination webserver. The problem is that, when trying to connect to my server using his private key, the key is "scrambled", as described by the school's IT managers. Because of this, their key is identified as invalid and they are unable to connect.

This is my first time (second, actually - [was redirected from network engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38553/ssh-with-private-public-keypair-not-working-under-proxy)) asking a question on the stackexchange network, please inform me if there are any ways I can improve my question.

Thanks,

~ Bob

Comment: Waiiit, even if the school performs TLS MiTM with its own certificate, why would it affect SSH which is a completely separate protocol? My own guess would be that the IT "managers" just block SSH outright and don't want to admit it.

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was confusing, as a connection to the server was possible, but the server refused the key submitted by the client. I'm wondering if the connection even made it out of the network at all, or if it was being redirected within the network.
The issue suddenly disappeared, and the IT managers are now unblocking the necessary port - Thank you for your input.

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Comment: Noticed myself, but still don't know how to gain access to the old one.

Comment: The other one is https://superuser.com/users/692888/bob-sharp. This one is https://superuser.com/users/692898/oasis9-bob-sharp. Include these 2 accounts the [contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact)